# Get the hashed entityId on newly created tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to programatically create a link to a tab I just created in MS Teams with the following format:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/${appId}/${entityId}?context={"channelId":"${channelId}"}
```

I know the appId. I can get the channelId from `microsoftTeams.getContext`. The problem is with the entityId.

We have a really long entityId, which is a large stringified JSON configuration object. Creating the tab works, but when I get a link for the tab via the UI, the entityId looks something like:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/{appId}/_djb2_msteams_prefix_4000611857?context=...
```

It seems that MS Teams is using some djb2 hashing algorithm to encode the long entityId we provide. Using the link with the dbj2-hashed entity ID works. Using a link we create with the actual entityId (stringified and url-encoded) does not work.

How can I create the djb2 hash of the entityId? Alternatively, how I can use a long entityId to create a link to the tab?

Answer (score 1):

> Using a link we create with the actual entityId (stringified and url-encoded) does not work.

The entityId we created *should* work, but there was some issues the contents. The original entityId was something like

```
JSON.stringify(
  {
    url: encodeURIComponent('https://link.to.website/path?with&searchquery')
  }
)
```

The encoded `%` characters caused the link to not resolve correctly. I ended up solving the issue by encoding the entityId a little differently. It takes a little more effort to parse, but everything works now.

```
btoa(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(
  {
    url: encodeURIComponent('https://link.to.website/path?with&searchquery')
  }
)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to generate a "Deep Link" to your tab, in which case this should help: [Generating a deep link to your tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab). It includes examples showing how to deep link to an individual item in the tab, pass in context, etc.

Some parts can be a little confusing, but give it a go and it should do what you need.

Comment: That's my starting point, but my issue is the entityId I use doesn't actually work when put in the deep link.

Comment: So the docs are *technically correct*, but I found it actually a bit confusing the first time I tried deep linking, especially with regards two items:

1) The "EntityId" is the same "EntityId" you register in your manifest file (or App Studio) for your Tab

2) It's also important that your "AppId" is the AppId for your Teams App itself, NOT for, for example, your Microsoft AppId for your bot, registered in Azure.

Importantly, you should NOT be trying to "craft" the urls yourself - rather work on getting the deep linking working properly.  Hope that helps?